# naming of transitions (events) in state machines

Tags: naming-conventions, state-machine

Should you name events (transitions) in an FSM after the states themselves? Or is there an accepted convention? For example, in ruby's `state_machine` you'd have `machine.event!` and `machine.state?`. If events and states are the same than the only difference between a check and transition is `?` and `!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use such naming for Mealy machines, since actions with different logic should have different names. Other than that I don't see a problem with this approach.